# What will be the time complexity of the following code?

Tags: java, time-complexity

```
for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int j = i;j<=n;j++)
    {
        //statement -> O(1)
    }
}
```

The time complexity of the first loop (i) is O(n). I mainly have a problem with the second loop.

Thanks!

Comment: You can count this as O(n*n) cause second loop will still run O(n) for first iteration, then n-1, n-2, n-3, ...

Comment: Ask yourself what the mean number of iterations of the second loop is over i=1 to i=n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall time (asymptotic analysis) TC would be O(n^2), there will not be exactly n^2 operations!!